# How to Lock cells in SSRS while exporting to Excel?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, locking, ssrs-2008

I have a report in SSRS 2008. I need to export it to excel and lock some columns and rows.
For example I have 10 columns and 500 rows in excel.

1- I want first two column can't be edited. Other columns can be.

2- Also new rows can be added.

3- Is there any way to set track changes mode or protect sheet in SSRS while exporting excel?

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert on SSRS but It seems you can manually set in the following file: Aspose.Cells.ReportingServices.xml.

Please look at following link for details:
[Aspose Forum Link](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/310260/310260/showthread.aspx)